# Create virtual layer without geometry from code

Tags: qgis, pyqgis-3, virtual-layer

I'm trying to create virtual layer to calculate count of features in layer "polygon_layer". I have no problem to create virtual layer from DB Manager. But if I do it in my python plugin, the result is None. Code:

```
qStr = ('?query = select polygon_type, count(*) as cnt from polygon_layer group by polygon_type order by 1')
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer( qStr, "Count Types", "virtual" )
```

The virtual layer has not geometry. And as I understand it's necessary to determine geometry type of virtual layer as "No geometry".
My QGIS version is 3.4.

Answer (score 3):

Error in url. No spaces before "=".

```
qStr = ('?query=select polygon_type, count(*) as cnt from polygon_layer group by polygon_type order by 1&nogeometry')
```

If the key "nogeometry" is set then vlayer.geometryType() is QgsWkbTypes.NullGeometry, otherwise it's QgsWkbTypes.UnknownGeometry